# Solution in "Think Python" for Ex 4.3 #1 doesn't work

Tags: python

I am having some issue with an exercise 4.3 #1 in "ThinkPython". The solution given in the book to the exercise doesn't seem to work.

**Problem:**
"Write a function called square that takes a parameter named t, which is a turtle. It should use the turtle to draw a square.
Write a function call that passes bob as an argument to square, and then run the program again"

**Solution** (FROM THE BOOK!)

```
def square(t):
    for i in range(4):
        t.fd(100)
        t.lt(90)
square(bob)
```

**ERROR:**

```
line 5, in <module>
    square(bob)
NameError: name 'bob' is not defined
```

Why doesn't recognize bob as a parameter of square?

Comment: How did you define ```bob = ?```?

Comment: `bob` is not defined. Either you missed part of the exercise, or the exercise is nonsense.

Comment: Either your book also defines `bob` and you should do it too. Or change your book.

Comment: In your own words, where the assignment specification says "Write a function call that passes bob as an argument to square,", what do you think *the book* expects `bob` to refer to? You should try reading the surrounding text. They might, for example, expect your exercise code to continue on from example code given in the main text.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark This code is clearly using the [`turtle` standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html), which implements [turtle graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_graphics) using a Tkinter graphics context. While OP should have mentioned this, the code is distinctive enough that, along with the exercise text, this is the only reasonable explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice in the description of the problem:

> Write a function called square that takes a parameter named t, which is a turtle.

Basically, you'll need to define a [`Turtle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.Turtle) object to pass into the parameters of your function, like so:

```
import turtle

def square(t):
    for i in range(4):
        t.fd(100)
        t.lt(90)

bob = turtle.Turtle()
square(bob)
```

Output:

[image]

---

UPDATE:

Responding to the OP's comment, in order to make the function define its own turtle for every call of itself, simply remove the `t` from the arguments, and add `t = turtle.Turtle()` into the function:

```
import turtle

def square():
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    for i in range(4):
        t.fd(100)
        t.lt(90)

square()
```

Comment: thank you so much! This makes sense for someone like me is new to coding. Looking at your example, I was wondering if there is a way to re-write the function square so that we don't have to define every time that the argument is a turtle object. I tried to add to the function a line like  "t = turtle.Turtle"  but it didn't seems to work. I hope that my question makes sense.

Comment: @MattiaBegali Close! I've added an update addressing your comment. Happy new year :)

Comment: thanks! this is great and very helpful! Happy new year to you too!

Answer (score -2):

`bob` is recognized as a parameter, the only thing is that `bob` is supposed to be wrapped around quotation marks, whether it be single quotes or double.

In this scenario, `bob` is being passed into the function and look like it is treated as a number, but alphabetic characters will always correspond to strings.

Sorry if this answer is incorrect, I am not very experienced in Turtle Shell Graphics as a whole.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer] and try to stick to topics where you are reasonably confident your answer is correct. Since you're aware that the program is supposed to do something graphical, it should stand out to you that passing a string isn't likely to be useful. You should also notice that the calls `t.fd(100)` and `t.lt(90)` would not work if `t` were a string. Finally, you should read the description of the problem fully: it clearly says that `t` is expected to be "a turtle".